# Два Div'a в одну ширину , возможно другое решение

Tags: html, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Приветствую всех читающих , я начинающий верстальщик только изучаю , появилась такая проблема , мне нужно выстроить два блока Div в одну ширину(см.картинку) , также есть вопрос , посмотрев на изображение вы заметите что на нем есть блок с оражневыми часами , собственно сам вопрос , при позиционировании других блоков при помощи position:relative все они позиционируются не относительно общего блока Div , а относительно блока с оранжевыми часами , объясните мне пожалуйста почему так и как это исправить , а если же исправить это нельзя как все таки выстроить два дива в одну ширину , чтобы я смог без отрицательного значения позиционировать блоки.Пробовал дать двум дивам width:50% , но это не работает.

Comment: Не вижу картинку

Answer (score 1):

Тут не надо использовать ваши position'ы, достаточно дать родителю этих div'ов display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; вам останется задать ширину для этих дочерних div'ов. Но еще лучше будет прочитать вам о flexbox, там и ширину можно задавать через флексы.